# $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{strong}})) = C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}))$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Given a Banach space $X$, we have two topologies on the space of all bounded linear operators $L(X)$, one is [uniform operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_topologies#Introduction) $\mathcal T_{\text{strong}}$, the other is [strong operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology) $\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}$. We know that the topology $\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}$ is normable with the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) $\|\cdot\|$.

Now $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}))$ is the space of all function from $[0,T]$ to $L(X)$ that are continuous for the uniform operator topology. Clearly, it is normable with the supremum norm
$$\|F\|_\infty:=\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\|F(t)\|.$$

$C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{strong}}))$ is the space of all function from $[0,T]$ to $L(X)$ that are continuous for the strong operator topology. That is, $F\in C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{strong}}))$ if and only if for each $x\in X$, the function $t\to F(t)x$ is continuous.

How to compare these two spaces $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{strong}}))$ and $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}))$? Are they equal as sets? And how about their topologies? Are these two topologies equivalent?

---

The question is actually motivated by an argument in the book [*One-parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA514&dq=One-parameter+semigroups+for+linear+evolution+equations+A.7+Proposition&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiegoLw88feAhVMa94KHUh0APoQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=One-parameter%20semigroups%20for%20linear%20evolution%20equations%20A.7%20Proposition&f=false) by Engel & Nagel. See the last sentence in the picture below. How can they derive from
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(\cdot)x = F(\cdot)x, \ \text{in } C([0,t_0],X), \quad\forall x\in X,$$
to
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n = F, \ \text{in } \mathcal X_{t_0}.$$

> [image]

Comment: Strong = uniform

Comment: @DanielCamarenaPerez Can you explain more?

Comment: @DanielCamarenaPerez: The strong operator topology does not equal the uniform (i.e. operator norm) topology when $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge how define the strong topology?

Comment: @DanielCamarenaPerez: It's the strong **operator** topology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_operator_topology.  That is a different thing from the "strong topology".  The notation $\mathcal{T}_{\text{strong}}$ is just being used for shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are generally not equal as sets.

Take $X = L^1([0,1])$, and for $h \in X$ let $F(t)h = 1_{[0,t]} h$.  You can check, using the dominated convergence theorem, that for any fixed $h$, if $t_n \to t$ we have $1_{[0,t_n]}h \to 1_{[0,t]}h$ in $L^1$.  Hence $F : [0,1] \to L(X)$ is continuous when $L(X)$ is equipped with the strong operator topology.  However, for any $t > 0$, if we take $h = 1_{[0,t]}$ then $F(t)h = h$ and thus $\|F(t)\| \ge 1$, whereas $F(0)$ is the zero operator.  So $F$ is not continuous when $L(X)$ is equipped with the uniform topology.

That is, this particular function $F$ is in $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{strong}}))$ but not in $C([0,T],(L(X),\mathcal T_{\text{uniform}}))$.

---

For the proof in the book, there are a few more steps that have not been written out.

At this point, what has been shown is the following:

> For each fixed $x \in X$, the sequence of functions $t \mapsto F_n(t)x$ converges in sup norm to some function called $t \mapsto F(t)x$, which is continuous.

Now you have to verify the following:

- For each $t$, the map $x \mapsto F(t) x$ is linear.  Hence we can view $F(t)$ as a linear operator on $X$.
- For each $t$, the linear operator $x \mapsto F(t)x$ is bounded, i.e. $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|F(t)x\|_X < \infty$.  (You can use the uniform boundedness principle.)  Hence we can view $F$ as a function from $[0,t_0]$ into $L(X)$.
- Since we showed above that $t \mapsto F(t) x$ is continuous for each $x$, this shows that $F : [0,t_0] \to L(X)$ is continuous with respect to the strong operator topology.  So $F$ really is an element of $\mathcal{X}_{t_0}$.
- Show that $F_n$ converges to $F$ in the above norm.  That is, you must show
  $$\sup_{t \in [0,t_0]} \|F_n(t) - F(t)\|_{L(X)} := \sup_{t \in [0,t_0]} \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|F_n(t)x - F(t)x\|_{X} \to 0$$
  as $n \to \infty$.  This will be a typical sort of triangle inequality "$\epsilon/2$" argument.

  Specifically, fix $\epsilon > 0$.  Since $\{F_n\}$ is Cauchy, choose $N$ so large that $\|F_k - F_m\|_{\infty} < \epsilon/2$ for all $m, k > N$.  Choose an arbitrary $x \in X$ with $\|x\|_X = 1$.  Since $F_n(\cdot) x \to F(\cdot) x$ uniformly (which is the statement in the box above), we can find an $m > N$ such that for every $t \in [0,t_0]$ we have $\|F_m(t) x - F(t)x\|_X < \epsilon/2$.  We also have $$\|F_k(t)x - F_m(t)x\| \le \|F_k(t) -F_m(t)\|_{L(X)} \|x\| \le \|F_k - F_m\|_\infty \|x\| <\epsilon/2$$ as above, so by the triangle inequality, 
  $$\|F_k(t) x - F(t) x\|_X \le \|F_k(t) x - F_m(t) x\|_X + \|F_m(t) x - F(t) x\|_X < \epsilon.$$
  So we have $\|F_k(t) x - F(t) x\|_X < \epsilon$.  But $x$ and $t$ were arbitrary, so we have $$\sup_{t \in [0,t_0]} \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|F_n(t)x - F(t)x\|_{X} \le \epsilon.$$ This holds for all $k > N$, so we have shown the desired convergence.

Comment: Then can you explain the last sentence in the picture above?

Comment: I added a source link for the book by Engel & Nagel.

Comment: @Q.Huang: See edits.

Comment: Could you explain more for the "$\epsilon/2$" argument in the last step? I know that the continuity of the function $t\to F(t)x$ should play a role in this step, but I don't know how to use this...

Comment: $\|F(t)-F(0)\|=\|F(t)\|\ge {\|F(t)h\|}_{L^1}={\|h\|}_{L^1}= t$ if $h=1_{[0,t]}$?

Comment: @DanielCamarenaPerez: $\|F(t)\| \ge \|F(t)h\|/\|h\|$, and we have $\|F(t) h \| = \|h\| = t$.

Comment: @Q.Huang: See edit.  The continuity isn't really used, but the uniform convergence for each $x$ is used.

Comment: Great! The number $m$ depends on $x$ but $k$ not! Very nice argument, Thanks!